# Why am I getting invalid character

Tags: python-3.x

I am running a simple code with a GPS sensor and Raspberry Pi 3b+ and want to perform some calculations with the readings and the only errors I'm getting is "SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier" but the line looks straightforward.

```
def Tasks():
    def CalculateSpeed():
        if x[-1] and y[-1] == even:
            ChangeInLatitude=x1-x
            DistanceConversion=ChangeInLatitude*111111
            Speed=DistanceConversion/TimeElapsed
            Speed=str(speed) + meters/interval 
            print (“The object this module is attached to is moving at “ + Speed)
```

The error code is placing the error marker at the end of "the" in the 8th line

Comment: What is the meaning of the "Why" term at the end of the code line ```Speed=str(speed) + meters/interval Why```?

Comment: @itprorh66 i guess that was just a typo

Comment: It looks like, your compiler is interpreting the word 'object' as a python class/function.  From your code, I don't see why this is happening, but given that it displays the word  in the same font/style as other python class/functions (ie.e Tasks, CalculateSpeed,, print, and str.  That would be my guess is to what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have unicode quotes.

```
foo = “bar“
```

is not valid nor is

```
foo = “bar”
```

but single or double "basic" quotes are:

```
foo = "bar"
```

Comment: good catch I totally missed that little nuance.